# MONGODB Aggregate Function

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to calculate the average of ratings corresponding to doctor's id using MongoDB query(Version 3.2)

```
doctorsReview.aggregate(
        { 
            $group: {
            _id: "doctors_id", 
            averageRating: { $avg: "$rating" } 
            }

        }, function(error, result){
            if(error)
                console.log('cant calculate the average');
            else
            console.log(result);
        });
```

I am getting the error

```
doctorsReview.aggregate is not a function
```

TIA.

Comment: If you run on mongoshell, you need to add `db.` prefix to `doctorsReview.aggregate`.It will be like this `db.doctorsReview.aggregate`

Comment: i prefixed db. but now its showing db is not defined. i am using mongod.exe

Comment: i have resolved the issue,Thanks.

Comment: so what's the problem and the fix ?

Comment: it was an issue from my part,i just replaced doctorsReview.aggregate with DoctorsReview.aggregate . and i didnt required to use db as prefix.